# my PC showing grub rescue

Tags: boot

Two operating systems are installed on my laptop: first Ubuntu and second Windows 7.

But both are in same drive, that is the C: drive. I shrank 10 GB off the volume of C: drive and created a new drive with this much of volume and formatted this new drive.

Now, as I am starting my system, neither Windows nor Ubuntu are booting, it's displaying

```
no such partition found
```

ans

```
grub rescue>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to install Ubuntu after Windows. In order to fix the grub rescue, there is a nice tool: **boot-repair**. Just let boot-repair try to fix the problem. Some useful information about boot-repair can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair